# make fxml screen static, not able to open other running services

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, fxml, fxmlloader

i want to make a user not able to do anything else of my application, i want a user to do things available on my application only.
I will get this done on swing by Robot class, but in fxml i have no idea.
Can anybody guide me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

If you want the user to be restricted from interacting with the rest of your application while a window is open, then you could use `stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);`.

If you want the user to be restricted from interacting with **all** other application windows, you could use `stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);`.

If this is not what you were looking for, sorry in advance as your post kind of confused me. If this was not what you were looking for, could you try and clarify your question a little bit so I can understand it?

Thanks and good luck with your project!